# Add tool tip description next to product attribute dropdown menu woocommerce

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to add a tool tip to each product variation dropdown with a small description. Here is a screenshot of what I'm envisioning.

[image]

I thought about using CSS and adding the pseudo element :after, but I can't make it clickable. Also I don't see a hook to add content to each dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

I used a woocommerce hook (woocommerce_before_variations_form), bootstrap tooltip and css positioning to move the tooltip btn's where I wanted them.

**Woocommerce function:**

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_variations_form', 'krank_custom_action', 5 );

function krank_custom_action() {
  echo '<button class="krank-tooltip ttone" type="button" data- 
  toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Your text here">Your btn text</button>
  <button class="krank-tooltip tttwo" type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Your text here ">Your btn 
    text</button>';
}
```

**CSS:**

```
/* Tool tips */
button.krank-tooltip {border: none;color: #0157a3;}
button.krank-tooltip.ttone {position: relative;top: 73px;right: -273px;}
button.krank-tooltip.tttwo {position: relative;top: 114px;right: -161px;}
```